# Program crashing when creating linked lists in C

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I'm having problems creating a function that creates two separate linked lists in C.

In my program, the user enters an equation such as 7 + 9 * 8, character by character, the program then makes lists with them.

The code is as follows: (Where place is where is should be in the list and data is the number/operator itself. Both come from another part of the program)

```
struct trees {

    char data;
    int posicion;
    struct trees *next;
    struct trees *childI;
    struct trees *childD;

};

    struct trees *root;
    struct trees *operador_uno;
    struct trees *numero_uno;

    char *numeros;
    char *operadores;
    int num, num_operadores;


void crearLista(int place, char data) {

    int i;

    struct trees *temp1 = (struct trees *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct trees));

    temp1->data = data;

    if(place == 0) {
        if((data == '/') || (data == '*') || (data == '+') || (data == '-')){
            temp1->next = operador_uno;
            operador_uno = temp1;
        }
        else {
            temp1->next = numero_uno;
            numero_uno = temp1;
        }

    }

    else {

        struct trees *temp2;

        if((data == '/') || (data == '*') || (data == '+') || (data == '-')) {
            struct trees *temp2 = operador_uno;
        }
        else {
            struct trees *temp2 = numero_uno;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < place - 1; i++) {
            temp2 = temp2->next; // [CRASH]
        }

        temp1->next = temp2->next;
        temp2->next = temp1; // [CRASH]

    }


    for(i = 0; i < place && place != 0; i++) {
        struct trees *temp1 = operador_uno;
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < place + 1; i++) {
        struct trees *temp2 = numero_uno;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }

}
```

I identified through a tonne of printf statements that it will add the first **number** in the equation to the list successfully, how it does not add the first **operator** and with the second **number** the program crashes altogether.

The crashing problem appears to occur in the places I have written [CRASH], when I put temp2->next = temp1.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Learning to use [gdb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) would be a great gift to yourself in terms of time saved finding where things crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe not the only issue but:

```
    struct trees *temp2;

    if((data == '/') || (data == '*') || (data == '+') || (data == '-')) {
        struct trees *temp2 = operador_uno;  // not the same "temp2" as above
    }
    else {
        struct trees *temp2 = numero_uno;  // not the same "temp2" as above
    }

    for(i = 0; i < place - 1; i++) {
        temp2 = temp2->next; // [CRASH] because temp2 isn't initialized
    }
```

`struct trees *temp2 = operador_uno;` is *shadowing* `temp2` declared in the outer scope. So the outer `temp2` is never initialized, your initialization sets a value to a variable that goes out of scope.

So remove `struct trees *` so the same `temp2` variable is used (and initialised), like this (I'd prefer a ternary expression, though):

```
 if((data == '/') || (data == '*') || (data == '+') || (data == '-')) 
 {
    temp2 = operador_uno;
 }
else 
 {
    temp2 = numero_uno;
 }
```

And *turn on compiler warnings* which would have told you that:

- you're using the outer `temp2` uninitialized
- you're not using the inner `temp2` variables

Comment: Note that with gcc at least, you could  turn on `-Wshadow` to see the warning about shadows, and then you'd get even more warnings than the ones you've mentioned.